# TinyMce Error "Your browser doesn't support copy/paste" how to resolve?

Tags: javascript, tinymce, copy-paste, tinymce-5

I am usign tinymce version 5.10.2
However when i try to paste something into tinymce using contextmenu. I am getting below error please help.
"Your browser doesn't support direct access to the clipboard. Please use the Ctrl+X/C/V keyboard shortcuts instead."

Comment: Which browser?!

Comment: everyone. chrome,firefox

Comment: Clipboard API has some restrictions, check [the combatibility table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard_API#browser_compatibility).